# How to Overload Get Operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have a class which stores value.

```
public class Entry<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public Entry() { }    

    public Entry(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    // overload set operator.
    public static implicit operator Entry<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Entry<T>(value);
    }
}
```

To utilize this class:

```
public class Exam
{
    public Exam()
    {
        ID = new Entry<int>();
        Result = new Entry<int>();

        // notice here I can assign T type value, because I overload set operator.
        ID = 1;
        Result = "Good Result.";

        // this will throw error, how to overload the get operator here?
        int tempID = ID;
        string tempResult = Result;

        // else I will need to write longer code like this.
       int tempID = ID.Value;
       string tempResult = Result.Value;
    }

    public Entry<int> ID { get; set; }
    public Entry<string> Result { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm able to overload the set operator which I can straightaway do "ID = 1".

But when I do "int tempID = ID;", it will throw error.

How to overload the get operator so I can do "int tempID = ID;" instead of "int tempID = ID.Value;"?

Comment: You're going to have to add an operator to Entry type so that it can equal int.

Comment: Well, as soon as I leave the comment someone posts the example.  lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, add another implicit operator but for the other direction!

```
public class Entry<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public Entry() { }

    public Entry(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator Entry<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Entry<T>(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Entry<T> entry)
    {
        return entry.Value;
    }
}
```

And usage is a breeze:

```
void Main()
{
    Entry<int> intEntry = 10;
    int val = intEntry;
}
```